# How to create custom OTA update on AWS IoT?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I want to **update** some **python code** on **Raspberry pi Device** which is connected to **AWS IoT Core**.

***Note : I am not using Amazon FreeRTOS or Greengrass core.***

AWS has provision for **custom OTA updates** but it does not have any proper documentation on how to create job document. Also the documentation only has information of creating job update for FreeRTOS and Greengrass core.

I need help on **how to install OTA agent on Raspberry pi** and **how to create job document** (*document.json*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually AWS offers OTA only for FreeRTOS and Greengrass. For a Raspberry you need to handle the client side of the update yourself.
In case of python this is most likely a file exchange.

What AWS IoT Jobs can do for you is the job scheduling management (means if there is an update available and status handling) and artefact handling. The artefact is either some configuration in a JSON, a pre-signed S3 link or even login information for AWS ECS to download Docker images.

A good starting point is to create a job via the management console (IoT Core -> Manage -> Jobs -> Create -> Create a custom job)

The Job document, Jobs, Job executions are quite well described in the [AWS IoT Developer Guide - Jobs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-jobs.html)

The Job is described in the [Using the AWS IoT Jobs APIs - CreateJob](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/jobs-api.html) and contains a link to the job document (documentSource).